# How to pass a token around in a SQL script?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following 3 functions in SQL.

Register account:

```
create or replace function register 
    (email     text,
     username  text,
     password  text)
returns text
as $$
begin
    ...
end
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Activate account:

```
create or replace function activate 
    (token text)
returns void
as $$
begin
    ....
end
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Login to account:

```
create or replace function login 
    (username text,
     password text)
returns text
as $$
begin
end
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

How would I call all 3 functions in one go? I have tried using the `with` command but with no success

```
with account_activation_certificate as
(
    select
        *
    from
        register
        (
            'john@example.com',
            'john',
            'abcd1234'
        )
)
select
    *
from
    activate
    (
        select
            *
        from
            account_activation_certificate
    )
with
    jwt
as
(
    select
        *
    from
        login
        (
            'john',
            'abcd1234'
        )
    /* Additional queries using jwt */
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be getting confused with your parentheses. For example, a subquery must always be surrounded by (extra) parentheses.

This is a procedural requirement, so use procedural code:

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
DECLARE
   email text := 'john@example.com';
   username text := 'john';
   password text := 'abcd1234';
BEGIN
   PERFORM activate(
              register(email, username, password)
           );
   PERFORM login(username, password);
END;
$$;
```

The `DO` statement allows you to use procedural code in an SQL statement, in this case PL/pgSQL code.

Comment: Well i have a script with 100x users which need to register, activate, and login and then use the token to call other functions. I am trying to do it without variables

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using a PL/pgSQL function?

Comment: Technically, no there isn't. I simply assumed SQL philosophy was to not use variables where possible

Comment: Well, this is not SQL, it is PL/pgSQL wrapped in an SQL statement. This is of course a matter of opinion, but I believe in using the tool that is best suited for the purpose. You can certainly contrive to do that in a single standard conforming SQL statement, but it might me more complicated than using procedural code.